# Google Analytics: is there any value in adding the URL to a Click Event Category, Action or Label?

Tags: google-analytics

There is a slight disagreement here at our work place. Our Metrics team has us putting the URL into Google Analytics Event `Category`, `Actions` or `Labels`. As far as I can tell, it's redundant because then url appears as `dl` in the `Query String Parameters` when I view the click event in Devtool's Network panel.
Is there any value or reason to add the page URL to Event Category, Label or Action?
**Someone suggested this was a better location for this question then on Stack Overflow...

Comment: What type of event is it? Outbound click? Link to a brochure? Just to measure user interaction?

Comment: There are all different variations. An example would be the main logo in the header. The html is shared via PHP across pages. On the home page, clicking scrolls the page the to the top of the screen, on secondary pages it returns you to the home page. In all cases the Event Action is 'Brand Homepage - Image'.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to see in your reports. That said, it doesn't really make sense to have the URL in all the event parameters (cat, act, and lab), as you can already see that in other dimensions, but sometimes when an event, for example clicks to a Contact Us link, happens on any page in a footer, then you would want to include the URL, say, in the label, to show where the click happened from. One thing to note is that seeing data in the response header QSPs doesn't mean it will show up nice and neatly in the reports, so you may want to expose that data so it is more readily available, like in the event label (or action, or category).